# How to sort the values of an array according to the value of another array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
list1 = [{name: 'apple'}, {name: 'pear'}, {name: 'banana'}]
list2 = ['banana', 'apple', 'pear']
```

expectation

```
list1 = [{name: 'banana'}, {name: 'apple'}, {name: 'pear'}]
```

How to make `list2` and sort `list1` through angularjs ng-repeat or JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have and what you wannt to have . Here is how you get.

```js
list1 = [{name: 'apple'}, {name: 'pear'},{name: 'banana'}];
list2 = ['banana', 'apple', 'pear'];
var result = [];
function getData(){
list2.forEach(function(e){
  let obj=list1.find(element=>element['name'] === e);
  result.push(obj);
})
console.log(result);
}
getData();
// In case you want to preserve with list1
list1.sort(function(a, b){  
  return list2.indexOf(a.name) - list2.indexOf(b.name);
});
console.log(list1)
```

Now you can use `result` as inside  `ng-repeat` ;

Comment: @Scheinin glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

And a map solution

```js
var list1=[{
  name: 'apple'
}, {
  name: 'pear'
}, {
  name: 'banana'
}];
var list2 = ['banana', 'apple', 'pear'];

list1 = list2.map(x=>{
return {name:x};
});

console.log(list1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index of the array `list2` to get the numeric values for sorting:

```js
var list1 = [{
  name: 'apple'
}, {
  name: 'pear'
}, {
  name: 'banana'
}]
var list2 = ['banana', 'apple', 'pear'];
list1.sort(function(a, b) {
  return list2.indexOf(a.name) - list2.indexOf(b.name);
});
console.log(list1);
```

Comment: @Scheinin glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$scope.props = [{name: 'apple'}, {name: 'pear'}, {name: 'banana'}]

ng-repeat="prop in props | orderBy:'name'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `compare` function as below :

```js
var list1 = [{name: 'apple'}, {name: 'pear'}, {name: 'banana'}];
var list2 = ['banana', 'apple', 'pear'];

function comp(a, b) {
  return list2.indexOf(a.name) - list2.indexOf(b.name);
}

list1.sort(comp);

console.log(list1);
```